# serverless-offline: remote Lambda custom authorizer for API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-offline

I have declared an HTTP Proxy method on my API Gateway resource using CloudFormation syntax ([detailed in this earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129644/api-gateway-http-proxy-integration-with-serverless-offline-not-lambda-proxy).)

I am trying to attach a custom authorizer, of type "Request", which uses an existing AWS Lambda function. The serverless docs have [a decent example](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#share-authorizer) of setting up custom authorizers using CloudFormation. Meanwhile, *serverless-offline* [clearly supports](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/blob/6645eed1fe2a4a37e64981836da05accf905bb26/src/createAuthScheme.js#L56) (source) request-scoped custom authorizers.

I have closely cross-referenced the relevant AWS CloudFormation documentation for [AWS::ApiGateway::Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html?shortFooter=true#aws-resource-apigateway-method-examples) and [AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-authorizer.html?shortFooter=true#w2ab1c21c10c20c21c13),  together with the related serverless docs, in creating the below serverless template. But so far, I am not getting the expected output or behavior from *serverless-offline*.

### Resources are created without authorizers

When I boot up the below serverless configuration, no authorizers are loaded for my resource. I don't see what is wrong or missing in my `serverless.yml` file. Do you have any tips? Thanks in advance!

```
➜  serverless-offline-attempt git:(master) ✗ npm start

> @ start /Users/freen/src/apig/serverless-offline-attempt
> ./node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless offline

Serverless: Starting Offline: dev/us-east-1.

Serverless: Routes defined in resources:
Serverless: ANY /upstream/{proxy*} -> http://upstream.company.cool/{proxy}

Serverless: Offline listening on http://localhost:3000
```

### `serverless.yml`

The below template file includes the APIG resources and the authorizer configuration.

```yaml
service: company-apig
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  runtime: python2.7

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    resourceRoutes: true

resources:
  Resources:
    # Parent APIG RestApi
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: company-apig
        Description: 'The main entry point of the APIG'

    # Shared Authorizers
    AuthorizeCompanyJWTAccessToken:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:
        Name: AuthorizeCompanyJWTAccessToken
        Type: REQUEST
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        AuthorizerUri: 
          Fn::Join: 
            - ""
            - 
              - "arn:aws:apigateway:"
              - Ref: "AWS::Region"
              - ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/"
              - "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:jwt-tokens-staging-AccessTokenAuthorizer"
              - "/invocations"

    # Resource /upstream
    UpstreamResource:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: 'upstream'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi

    # Resource /upstream/{proxy+}
    UpstreamProxyPath:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Ref: UpstreamResource
        PathPart: '{proxy+}'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi

    # Method ANY /upstream/{proxy+}
    UpstreamProxyAnyMethod:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        AuthorizationType: CUSTOM
        AuthorizerId:
          Ref: AuthorizeCompanyJWTAccessToken
        HttpMethod: ANY
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
          Type: HTTP_PROXY
          Uri: http://upstream.company.cool/{proxy}
          PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        MethodResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        ResourceId:
          Ref: UpstreamProxyPath
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
```

**Related:**

- [Shared Lambda authorizer setup in Serverless Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302266/shared-lambda-authorizer-setup-in-serverless-framework?rq=1) (only loosely; the OP seeks a CloudFormation solution, but the answer does not use CF)

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm looking for the same use case. Did you make any progress running an authorizer before the resource route?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm also looking for the same solution, did you find any solution?